# string and date time error message - when using on the same formula-field

Tags: crystal-reports, crystal-reports-2010

I am new to CR and trying to get an invoice formula to read sometimes as a date and sometimes as a text. This depends on the "terms code" for the customer how they should pay: there are only 4 codes, and sometimes it is blank.

I tried with different syntax using

```
str() or totext
```

but I do not know the right formatting. See below for my attempt :)

```
if isnull({PAYTERMS.TERMSCODE}) then {INVOICE.DATE}
else if {PAYTERMS.TERMSCODE}=1 then {INVOICE.DATE}+30 
else if {PAYTERMS.TERMSCODE}=2 then {INVOICE.DATE}+45
else if {PAYTERMS.TERMSCODE}=3 then {INVOICE.DATE}
else if {PAYTERMS.TERMSCODE}=4 then "Upon Receipt"
else {INVOICE.DATE}
```

It keeps returning an error:

> a date is required here

Comment: Can you change the property name of Invoice? The error is speaking itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The result of the formula must be of the same datatype, you can't mix dates and strings.
So you have to convert the dates to string.

There's no `str()`-function in Crystal Reports as far as I know. I guess you mean `cstr()`.

It does not matter if you use the `cstr()` or `totext()` because `totext()` is just an alias for `cstr()`.

The formula should look as follows:

```
if isnull({PAYTERMS.TERMSCODE}) then cstr({INVOICE.DATE})
else if {PAYTERMS.TERMSCODE}=1 then cstr({INVOICE.DATE}+30)
else if {PAYTERMS.TERMSCODE}=2 then cstr({INVOICE.DATE}+45)
else if {PAYTERMS.TERMSCODE}=3 then cstr({INVOICE.DATE})
else if {PAYTERMS.TERMSCODE}=4 then "Upon Receipt"
else cstr({INVOICE.DATE})
```

Additionally you can set the second argument of `cstr()` to define the output format  of the date:

```
cstr({INVOICE.DATE}, "MM/dd/yyyy")    // Output will be like "03/26/2019"
```